# GetListAsync is returing records including IsDeleted as true

Tags: abp

I have an entity model inheriting ISoftDelete. When I delete a record using DeleteAsync, ABP sets IsDeleted as true successfully.

But it returns the soft deleted record when GetListAsync is used.

Using ABP 2.8.

```
using Volo.Abp;
using Volo.Abp.Domain.Entities;

namespace POC.DataModels
{
    public partial class Employee : Entity<int>, ISoftDelete
    {
        protected Employee()
        {

        }

        public Employee(int id)
         : base(id)
        {

        }
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public bool IsDeleted { get; set; }
    }
}

using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using POC.DataModels;
using Volo.Abp.Domain.Repositories;

namespace POC
{
    public class EmployeeService : PocAppService
    {
        private readonly IRepository<Employee> _employeeRepository;

        public EmployeeService(IRepository<Employee> employeeRepository)
        {
            _employeeRepository = employeeRepository;
        }

        public async Task<IReadOnlyList<Employee>> GetAllEmployeesAsync()
        {
            return await _employeeRepository.GetListAsync().ConfigureAwait(false);
        }

        public async Task DeleteEmployeeAsync(int employeeId)
        {
            await _employeeRepository.DeleteAsync(x=>x.Id == employeeId).ConfigureAwait(false);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Hi, which repository you use? I tried to reproduce your issue but I could not. Can you share a bit more details, like codes, using repositories etc.

Comment: I have updated my question with sample model and application service code.

**Note:** This issue happens only for tables in second Database. I have 2 data contexts in my application (One for Identity Server and another for application data)

Comment: Can you share your second dbcontext? I suspect that you haven't called base.OnModelCreating.

Comment: Thanks Kalkan. This was the problem, having `base.OnModelCreating(builder)` solves the problem